# Selector only works with components of same Module

Tags: angular

I have added TaskdetailComponent in appmodule. and its selector only works with the component where itself resides. and do not work with the components of other modules. get this error 
"If 'app-taskdetail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."

I am using Angular 5.

```
Taskdetail Component
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-taskdetail',
      templateUrl: './taskdetail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./taskdetail.component.css']
    })
    export class TaskdetailComponent implements OnInit {

    App Module
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent, DashboardComponent, ProjectdetailComponent, BoardComponent, TaskdetailComponent
      ],


      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ApproutingModule,
        RouterModule,
        MaterialModule,
        ProjectsModule,
        SettingsModule,
        TasksModule,
        UsersModule,
        HelperModule,
        SettingRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule
      ],
      exports: [
        TasksModule
      ],

      providers: [AuthService, AuthGuardService, HelperService  , AttachmentService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

    export class AppModule { }

Works with this component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-projectdetail',
  templateUrl: './projectdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projectdetail.component.css'],
})
export class ProjectdetailComponent implements OnInit {


Not Working with this component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-addproject',
  templateUrl: './addproject.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addproject.component.css']
})
export class AddprojectComponent implements OnInit {
```

Comment: check your letters carefully

Comment: Super checked bro

Comment: Are you importing your taskdetailcomponent in the other components that are calling it as well?

Comment: Please show the import code for both components (the one that works and the one that doesn't).

Comment: I have mentioned once in the declaration of AppModule, while want to use selector of TaskdetailComponent (app-taskdetail) in multiple components. in one component its working while give error when i use in another component.

Comment: @NathanBeck plz check the code

Comment: <app-taskdetail ></app-taskdetail>
using this in other component

Comment: also using   @Input() id: number;
  @Output() loadParentComponent = new EventEmitter(); in taskdetailcomponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must only declare a component **one time**. So you have to put your component in a **Shared Module**

> Declare these classes in exactly one module of the application. Declare them in a module if they belong to that particular module.
>   [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-classes-should-i-add-to-the-declarations-array)

Here my file tree to show you: [File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMjE.png)

*App Module*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ProjectDetailModule } from './projectdetail/projectdetail.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ProjectDetailModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*ProjectDetail Module (which simulate another module)*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProjectdetailComponent } from './projectdetail.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ProjectdetailComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    exports: [ProjectdetailComponent]
}) 
export class ProjectDetailModule {

}
```

*Shared Module*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TaskdetailComponent } from '../taskdetail/taskdetail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TaskdetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TaskdetailComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Here the result: 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcCAV.png)

Comment: my mistake was that I was not exporting my component. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As of your implementation the error will occur and here is why.

Your `ProjectdetailComponent` and `TaskdetailComponent` is in same module which is `AppModule`. But with one you say it doesn't work is `AddprojectComponent` which is declared inside another module which doesn't seems to know about `TaskdetailComponent`.

Hence the error is correct.

You can use a [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) which can import to each module to use if this kind of component to be used inside different module.

Quick check: Declare your `TaskdetailComponent` inside the module which declared `AddprojectComponent`. Error will go away. This isn't the best solution. Try to use it with shared module.

Comment: I have many modules in my project. those components do accept selector of TaskdetailComponent, which are in the same module (means the module which contains TaskdetailComponent in declarations).  but components of other modules donot accpet selector of TaskdetailComponent . this is the real issue.

Comment: Now I don't know which module I should add TaskdetailComponent to. It can't be added in multiple modules. because an error will be thrown.

Comment: Yes, I’ve also given you a link. Refer to that. Create a SharedModule and include this TaskDetailComponent there. Then import it inside the module you want. Use the selector inside the components which declared inside the module (same module which you have imported SharedModule)

Comment: I see some guy got the idea of my answer. Hope you’ve got the idea.